# SQL Create Column & Union All error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assuming that all my field names are right.

1. MY query is creating a rank 1,2,3 base on the `DesCount`
2. I created a new column and named it as `GroupType`

My problem: When I use my newly created column `GroupType` and reference it in the `rank = rownumber over (partition` function, it gives me this error saying:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Invalid column name 'GroupType'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Invalid column name 'GroupType'.
```

Below is my SQL query:

```
select * from (
  select 
    D1,[DesCount], Type, [Caused], [Comm], DATE, 'IC' As GroupType,
    rank = row_number() over (partition by Date, [GroupType] order by date, [GroupType], [DesCount] desc)
  from Z_DefectCount
) t 
where rank <= 3
```

Thank you all for your help

Comment: why do you need to partition and order by const value?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column alias at the same level it is defined.  But you don't need it, because it is constant.  You also don't need to repeat the `partition by` expressions in the `order by` expressions.

This should do what you want:

```
select *
from (select D1, [DesCount], Type, [Caused], [Comm], DATE, 'IC' As GroupType,
             rank = row_number() over (partition by Date order by [DesCount] desc)
      from Z_DefectCount
     ) t 
where rank <= 3
```

Comment: I need those two [GroupType] in there because I am trying to do a union all. I'm trying to combine three different fields and put it in the GroupType column, then have it order as sequence above. I hope that make sense

Comment: @Nguyenal07 . . . Then either repeat the expression in the `rank()` or use a subquery to define the value.

Comment: can you please show me an example? I am new to SQL. Thanks